# Spring Amqp client recover

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, recovery

In my project, I occasionally encounter the situation where the consumer bound to a RabbitMQ queue disappears, which usually occurs after RabbitMQ itself recovers from a failure, but I can't determine the nature of the failure. This situation prevents my consumers from continuing to consume messages on RabbitMQ until re-boot my process. I've looked through the Spring Boot documentation and found some parameters that can be configured for retries. Are these parameters used for configuring consumer reconnection? or these are other way to solve this problem?

[image: rabbitmq retry properties]
My project uses Spring Boot version 2.7.18 and Spring AMQP version 2.4.17.
Thanks a lot.